# декодирование архива zip Base64

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Я получаю  XML в нем есть атрибут закодированный в Base64 - архив zip. Подскажите как декодировать и сохранить zip архив локально?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```pascal
uses
  System.NetEncoding;

var
  data: TBytes;
  strm: TStream;
begin
  data := TNetEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes(str);
  strm := TFileStream.Create('filename.zip', fmCreate or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    strm.WriteBuffer(data[0], Length(data));
  finally
    strm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Для более старых версий Delphi нужно использовать модуль `Soap.EncdDecd` и функцию оттуда `DecodeBase64`